# How to give MUi-TextField diff color on focued state, like green on focus and red on focus+error

Tags: material-ui, textfield

I want to give my Outlined textField green color on focus and if error occurs durring typing, then color should be changes to red.
But in my case if I am giving

```
"& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: 'green'
      },
    },
```

if shows green on error too during focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Mui-focused` is a separate class than `.Mui-error`, so you'll have to override each individually. See the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/outlined-input/#css) for a full list of all CSS classes available on this component.

Here is an example of customizing multiple classes:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'

const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
  '& label.Mui-focused': {
    color: 'green',
  },
  '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
    borderBottomColor: 'green',
  },
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
    '& fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'red',
    },
    '&:hover fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'yellow',
    },
    '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'green',
    },
  },
})
```

Here is a live demo of customized `OutlinedInput`components.

[image: Edit CustomizedInputs Material Demo]

[image]